# What expected Java byte code generate for generic class?

Tags: java

What the expected compile class for this **java generic code** :

```
public Class Abc<T extends Number>{

    private List<T> list;

    public void add(List<Number> argList){

//Expected line for generic replace with List or not

    List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<>();

    Object obj = 3;

    //Expected line for this object cast
    innerList.add((int)obj);
    }
    }
```

What the expected output for every generic statements.

Comment: Why do you need to know that and what do you try to achieve?

Comment: I don't expect anything. I just compile it; and if I care about the bytecode, I use `javap`.

Comment: Type eraser not working for java.util.Map for command javap -verbose java.util.Map

Comment: At the time of write any generic code if you don't know what the expected code generate for that thing it not cool :)

Answer (score 1):

The type definitions are retained within the .class file as a `Signature`

see

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3

and

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.4

Their only purpose is to provide more context when outputting bytecode in a human readable form.

During runtime, the typings are ignored and unused